# How to access / save cookies in Java

Tags: java, cookies, save

I am writing some software in Java.

I am testing the cookie managment functionality but I can't seem to get cookies working. I wrote a quick PHP that drops a cookie, and I tested that in my browser and the cookie drops fine.

However, take a look at this code:

```
    CookieManager cManager = new CookieManager();
    CookieHandler.setDefault(cManager);
    try
    {

        URL url = new URL("http://localhost/_techfactory/apage.php");
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        CookieStore cookieJar = cManager.getCookieStore();
        List<HttpCookie> cookies = cookieJar.getCookies();
        for ( HttpCookie cookie : cookies)
        {
            System.out.print(cookie);
        }
        Boolean isittrue = cookies.isEmpty();
        System.out.print(isittrue);
        BufferedReader bin = new BufferedReader ( new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ( ( line = bin.readLine()) != null )  
        System.out.print(line);

    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

This, although being syntactically correct, doesn't output anything, except the HTML from the page. Now by all accounts, the CookieManager implementaiton is a concrete implementation of CookieHandler, CookiePolicy and CookieStore. However, it just refuses to work for me, what I am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the HTTP header fields before checking the cookie store, and calling `openConnection()` does not read the HTTP headers.  See the first few lines of [the javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html).

If you need the cookies during processing, calling `getInputStream()` connects and parses the header fields, as will some of the other methods in URLConnection.

Comment: That is an interesting answer. However, when I connect to a remote website with this code, and not "localhost", the cookie seems to drop fine. For example I tested it with "http://www.google.co.uk". Any particular reason you think this doesn't work on locahost? Cookie acceptance policy?

Comment: I don't see what you're seeing--when I try your code with www.google.com, it shows no cookies.  If I reorder the code (read content, then check cookies) it shows one cookie.

Comment: How do you process the headers? I modified the code a little:

`code:


          URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            BufferedReader bin = new BufferedReader ( new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String line;`

And it seemed to work: The output can be found here: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/33/outputx.png/ . 
Google.com drops several cookies? Unless this is not the real output from the cookies?